# Add Create Task Radio Button in Calendar Module-suiteCRM?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm, sugarbean

I am new to suiteCRM and i need some help.When I want to add any activity(like Task,Meeting or Call) in calendar module,When I click on any time period then quick create popup is displays and it is showing two radio button "Schedule Meeting" and "Log Call" but it is not showing "Create Task" Which I want.

Is there any option in admin panel or config that allow us to enable crate task?
I have attached a screenshot for reference.

Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11C1V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an admin option per se.

In order to add tasks in that view, you would need to add the checkbox in  **modules/Calendar/tpls/form.tpl** and include your own custom javascript to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for comment.I added : {literal}<input type="radio" id="radio_task" value="Tasks" onclick="CAL.change_activity_type(this.value);" checked="true" name="appttype" tabindex="100"/>{/literal}
 <label for="radio_task">{$MOD.LBL_CREATE_TASK}</label> on modules/Calendar/tpls/form.tpl but the Create Task radio button is not showing.Am i missing sth?

Comment: Run repair and rebuild. If you on a development instance, you could enable development mode in the system settings.

Comment: Thanks for help Daniel.I  added the radio buttons but when i try to save data it shows "error while saving".I searched on forums of suitecrm  https://www.suitecrm.com/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/9379-add-create-task-radio-button-in-calendar-module and it is still an unsolved question.

Comment: I vote it up.And about the second problem with showing "error while saving" if you have any idea why it is showing will be very helpfull for me.